# Do something specific if python scripts exits because of error

Tags: python, loops, automation

My script sometimes errors which is fine, but I have to manually restart the script.

Anyone knows how to make it so that it actually works infinitely even if it crashed 50 times, currently what I have only works for 1 crash.

```
try:
    while True:
        do_main_logic()


except:
    continue
```

I have tried many scripts, but I am expecting it to just continue no matter what.

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021166/how-to-restart-a-python-program-after-it-crashes) provide relevant info. Basically, you'll need something outside your program to restart it in the event it crashes. Most developers would try to address the cause of the crash as well.

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean with "crash". If the full program is going down follow the advice of @eisaac. If the program throws a Python exception then my answer might help.

Comment: Use `except Exception:`, not `except:`. Do you really want to catch things like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`, making it nearly impossible to terminate your script without something extreme like `kill -9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap only `do_main_logic()` in a try-except block, not the full loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        pass
```

Caveat: Catching bare exceptions is frowned upon for good reason. It would be better if you could specify the type(s) of exceptions you expect. To cite the [Programming Recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) in the Style Guide for Python Code:

> When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except:` clause.

> A bare `except:` clause will catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use `except Exception:` (bare `except` is equivalent to `except BaseException:`).

Answer (score -2):

You want to do it forever ?
Just add a while :)

```
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            do_main_logic()


    except:
        continue
```